# Cursor keeps selecting vertices through the mesh without X-Ray on

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

When i try to select vertices on the side of a mesh, the vertices on the other side of the mesh is also being selected, as if i had X-Ray mode on. I cant figure out what could be the problem.

Here's a video to better understand the problem.

https://share.getcloudapp.com/Qwul0meR

I dont have X-Ray on, and i dont know anything else that would disable this.

Update: So apparently its not actually selecting through the vertices, but rather only through the mesh. Here's a video.

https://share.getcloudapp.com/nOuekZ2L

I cant find any options to disable this mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. First thing to do would be to make sure GPU drivers are up to date. Also try 2.83 version, see if maybe that is fixed already.

You could also see if enabling or disabling OpenGL Depth Picking has any effect on the issue:
[image]

If the problem persists, you should probably report it as a bug providing as much detailed info as possible.